# How to prevent the last tick from rendering? Using 'recharts' library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, recharts

I have a chart with `reversed` yAxis. How do I prevent **last tick** *(in this case it's number 8)* from rendering? [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liubko/x1yoboc7/654/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with a bit of css:

`.recharts-y-axis .recharts-cartesian-axis-tick:last-child {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: Thanks! It's so obvious, no idea why I haven't thought to do it with CSS :confused: